# PyCharm unable to refactor python @unique decorated enum member - expected behavior?

Tags: python, enums, pycharm

PyCharm 2022.3.1, Build #PY-223.8214.51, built on December 20, 2022

python 3.10.6

If enum is decorated @unique *and* is declared in a separate file, pycharm will not find usages to refactor/rename. Likewise, usages are not provided with context option to refactor/rename.

Declaration:

```
# file: pycharm_enum_dec.py

from enum import Enum, unique


@unique
class MyType(Enum):
    AAA = 'aaa'
    BBB = 'bbb'
```

Usage:

```
# file: pycharm_refac_enum.py

from pycharm_enum_dec import MyType

print(MyType.AAA)
```

Is this something inherent to the @unique decorator or a bug in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has confirmed that this is a bug with PyCharm treatment of @unique decorator. They have assigned it for resolution. No ETA (at 2023-01-17).